# C++ api for memcache

Tags: c++, memcached

I need to acccess memcache from my C++ application. In oerder to avoid reinventing the engine, I have been searching for existing libraries. Suprisingly, there are very few of them around (for the most part, interfacing is done in C not C++).

However, I have found two - both of which have very early version numbers, and appear to be "dead" projects (development appears to have ceased.

a. libmemcache-1.40.rc2
b. memcachedpp-0.1

I have a few questions:

1. Is anyone outhere aware of a good/reliable C++ memcache library?
2. Has anyone used any of the above libraries - if yes, which one would they recommend and why?

Comment: The latest activity reported on http://sourceforge.net/projects/memcachepp/ is 33 days ago. What makes you think it is dead?

Answer (score 3):

I've used this http://libmemcached.org/libMemcached.html and I recommend it